# Set Polling Interval on Python Openzwave

Tags: python, z-wave

How can I set a polling interval for devices on Python-Openzwave. The command
**network.set_polling_interval(time)** does not seem to change the default polling interval

**Code**

```
network = ZWaveNetwork(options, autostart=False)

dispatcher.connect(louie_network_started,ZWaveNetwork.SIGNAL_NETWORK_STARTED)
dispatcher.connect(louie_network_failed, ZWaveNetwork.SIGNAL_NETWORK_FAILED)
dispatcher.connect(louie_network_ready, ZWaveNetwork.SIGNAL_NETWORK_READY)


network.start()
network.set_poll_interval(1000)
print network.get_poll_interval()
```

Here it seems to be set to the value specified

```
#We wait for the network.
#print "***** Waiting for network to become ready : "
for i in range(0,90):
if network.state>=network.STATE_READY:
    #print "***** Network is ready"
    break
else:
    #sys.stdout.write(".")
    #sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1.0)


 print network.get_poll_interval()
```

Here its reset to the default value

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

From the [inline documentation of `python-openzwave`'s `network.py`](https://github.com/OpenZWave/python-openzwave/blob/master/src-api/openzwave/network.py), the function is not `set_polling_interval`, but actually

```
def set_poll_interval(self, milliseconds=500, bIntervalBetweenPolls=True):
```

Where `milliseconds` is

> [the] length of the polling interval in milliseconds

and `bIntervalBetweenPolls` is a boolean, which

> [if] set to true (via SetPollInterval), the `pollInterval` will be interspersed between each poll (so a much smaller `m_pollInterval` like 100, 500, or 1,000 may be appropriate). If false, the library attempts to complete all polls within `m_pollInterval`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually meant set_poll_interval . What happens s, it is changed to the value I want, but then it automatically switches back to the default. I checked this by printing the output from network.get_poll_interval(). Any reason why this would happen?

Comment: Could you update with more code showing where you set it and where it appears to be reset to default?